# Calculated column returns value from another list

Tags: list, column

How can I use calculated column to return a value from another list in SharePoint?

Comment: Can you please let us know in detail what you are trying to achieve? It will then be easier to decide which field to use rather than asking directly about calculated column.

Comment: Use LookUp columns or workflows to retrieve data from other lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Calculated columns only work with the current list, with the current list item.

Comment: This does answer the question. SharePoint only allows Users to access the current List/Row. Source: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-common-formulas-in-sharepoint-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3

Comment: I want the answer to be short and correct. "You can't do it" is the correct answer, it's not a criticism and I don't need more clarifications.